# Copying Database from assets folder to database folder

Tags: android, sqlite, android-file

Hi
I'm working with this code
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
and it's working fine, except that I'm getting a java.io.filenotfoundexception on this line

```
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
```

I also tried this instead

```
OutputStream myOutput = this.context.openFileOutput(outFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and I got

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   File
>   /data/data/com.kosherapp/databases/applicationdata
>   contains a path separator

Anyone have any ideas for me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150728075048/http://www.reigndesign.com:80/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) uses **[SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)** in the newer version the main class has a variable ASSET_DB_PATH :

```
public class SQLiteAssetHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String ASSET_DB_PATH = "databases";
```

**So you don´t need to specify in your class that extends from `SQLiteAssetHelper` the path of your database including the directory**

```
//  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databases/myadtabase.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
```

So instead of having:

```
"databases/databases/mydatabase.db"
```

you will have the correct path:

```
"databases/mydatabase.db"
```

[image]

---

Thats the reason for what you have this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File ............ contains a path
> separator

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
myDbHelper.close();
```

---

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.test/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "testdb.sqlite";
public static final int DB_Version = 1;

private final Context myContext;
private static SQLiteDatabase myDB;

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_Version);
    this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    onCreate(db);
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created
        // into the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    return myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDB != null)
        myDB.close();
    super.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), The name you supply to `openFileOutput` can't contain a path seperator.  It must be a file name only (this is to prevent you from attempting to write outside of your application's sandbox).  Looking at your error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   File
>   /data/data/com.kosherapp/databases/applicationdata
>   contains a path separator

Try using "applicationdata.db" as the file name by itself.

Comment: I thought of that, but then how do I know where it was copied to, since I'll need to read from it, and can I tell it to copy to the databases folder?

Answer (score 0):

Android 1.6 doesn't need you to specify the URL, just give name of database and your are all set to go. :)